# Stored Procedure PRINT each row value

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure where I like to display each Name in the table below 
on a separate line with a PRINT so the user can see what has been retreived:

```
  Select Name from Persons;
```

What is the best way to do this as I can use a cursor and then through each iteration display the Name with the PRINT. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `print` in "SQL"). Please add the tag for the database product you are using

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Writing procedures heavily differs from DBMS to DBMS. And why don't you just present the result to the user to enable them to see what has been selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way would be to select the output you want to show the user at the end of the procedure:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.test
AS
BEGIN
    --do stuff
    INSERT INTO foo (bar)
    SELECT name
    FROM persons

    --select what to show user
    SELECT name
    FROM persons
END
```

Answer (score 0):

PRINT doesn't work inside a stored procedure.

If you run the code without being wrapped in a SP, it will display what you want.